# use Label and Value of f:selecteItems with rich:combobox

Tags: jsf, richfaces

How can i display Label from SelecteItem and use the value as a Key in rich:combobox? Jboss forums says it is not possible since the rich:combobox is designed for suggestion. Not really a replacement for h:selectOneMenu . is there any work around or alternative way?

PS: i tried using JSF converter it is modifying both value and label.

Answer (score 0):

no.
use selectOneMenu.
add a4j:support as a child if you want ajax.